# Get information on tools/packages that are not installed

Tags: package-management, man

How can I get information about packages I have not installed (other than a web search)?

For example, imagine I am interested in `iftop`. If I do a web search I can find a wikipedia article and the man page, but how can I find information like that from the terminal without using a browser?

Comment: What OS? Do you have to see the manpage, or is a description of the package enough?

Comment: In most cases you cannot. Documentation (like *man* or *info* pages) usually cames with package itself. Some package managers offers very brief overview of the software before you install it, but it is not extended manual).

Comment: On what distribution? Package management is very distribution-dependent.

Answer (score 1):

If you're on a Debian based system (i.e. Ubuntu) you can use the apt-cache command to obtain the description of the package. Anything more detailed (man/info pages) would only be available for installed packages.

```
$apt-cache -f search iftop

Package: iftop
Description-md5: f7e93593aba6acc7b5a331b49f97466f
Description-en: displays bandwidth usage information on an network interface
 iftop does for network usage what top(1) does for CPU usage. It listens to
 network traffic on a named interface and displays a table of current bandwidth
 usage by pairs of hosts. Handy for answering the question "Why is my Internet
 link so slow?".
```

**Edit:**
Alternatively you could download *all* of the manual pages for later offline viewing.
See [Ubuntu Manual Project](http://ubuntu-manual.org/downloads) or the [Linux Documentation Project](http://tldp.org/manpages/man.html).